# Twitter Bootstrap v2.1.0 play framework 2 - images and JavaScript plugin not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, playframework-2.0

I have followed steps [here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Tips) to use bootstrap v2.1.0 with play 2 framework and I using the Build.scala configuration file. I can use basic css functions very nicely and I am pleased with this. When I am trying to use glyphicons icons and javascript functions I am not able to use them, has anyone gone through same issue? please help me on this.

File structure:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/ <<--- all less files are here

public/images/bootstrap/ <<-- glyphicons images are here

public/javascripts/    <<--- all javascripts are here
```

According to tutorial I have modified  variables.less as:

```
@iconSpritePath:          "/assets/images/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings.png";
@iconWhiteSpritePath:     "/assets/images/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white.png";
```

I have little concern with code for adding javascript:

```
for i in `ls javascripts/*`; do echo '<script src="@routes.Assets.at("'$i'")"></script>' | sed 's/\.js/.min.js/g'; done
```

where do I need to add it exactly?

Please excuse me if my question is flawed. I would appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

--------------------[edits]--------------------------
main view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css")" />
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        @content

        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap-affix.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap-alert.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap-button.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap-carousel.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap-collapse.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap-dropdown.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap-modal.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap-popover.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap-scrollspy.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap-tab.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap-tooltip.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap-transition.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap-typeahead.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.min.js")"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

----------------------------other view------------------------

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
         $('#nishi').popover();
        });
        </script>


  <a href="#" id="nishi" class="btn btn-primary" rel="popover" data-content="this is the body" data-original-title="this shoul be title">Check pop over</a>
```

Comment: Please show your `routes` file in order to see the config of your Asset controller.

Comment: @nico_ekito - Thanks for your comment my routes is **GET     /assets/*file             controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relative paths for the images:

```
// Sprite icons path
// -------------------------
@iconSpritePath:          "../../images/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings.png";
@iconWhiteSpritePath:     "../../images/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white.png";
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this is also not working, is their any other way to deal with this.

Comment: What is the location of your `bootstrap.min.css`?

Comment: **stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css** and it is linked in main.scal.html as **<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css")" />**

Comment: Any Build.scala is having definition as **def customLessEntryPoints(base: File): PathFinder = (
      (base / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" / "bootstrap" * "bootstrap.less") +++
      (base / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" * "*.less")
  )**

Comment: With this I can use basic functions like buttons but could not get images and javascripts. And the whole reason is these files are not getting loaded and here I am stuck

Comment: Okay, try `"../../images/glyphicons-halflings.png";` and `"../../images/glyphicons-halflings-white.png";`

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that you put the images in `assets/images/bootstrap/...` so add the `bootstrap/` in my above statement.

Comment: not this one as well, firebug says **failed to open given url**

Comment: awesome, this is working very well, thanks a lot man! Could you please suggest changes for javascript, as still I am not able to use javascript files.

Comment: Please post the generated Javascript links.

Comment: In my question above I have pasted generated javascript links

Comment: I meant the links that are in your actual HTML-File. Not the one you enter in the sourcecode, but the one your browser displays.

Comment: **http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-alert.min.js** and same for others

Comment: okay, and have you doublechecked that the files are actually there? ;)  that is `/public/assets/javascripts/...`

Comment: Yes, all are there. Just now I tried moving files from **public/javascripts/** to **app/assets/javascripts/** and all are loading, is it wrong to do?

Comment: I didn't know that you can do that. I always thought that there is only coffeescript allowed.

Comment: anyways for now I am keeping .js file there only, let me know if you got any idea on that. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For me, your images config is ok, please show some HTML colde how you use it.

For the javascripts, use them like this in your HTML template (here is an example, complete with the Bootstrap's javascripts you need):

```
<html>
   <head>
      ...
      <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap-dropdown.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap-alert.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <!-- Add other needed Bootstrap's javascripts-->
      ...
   </head>
<body>...
```

Comment: I have edited my question, I tried checking it in Crome and I am getting error for all these files, as these are not getting loaded. I am not getting why this is happening?